# Is there a way of controlling the version of the Model?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I have one workspace A and a workspace B and I am looking to copy models from workspace A to workspace B.

Let's say the model **M_1** is in version **V_1** in workspace A. I would like to register this model **M_1** in workspace B with the *same* version **V_1**.

Using the [register method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.model.model?view=azure-ml-py#register-workspace--model-path--model-name--tags-none--properties-none--description-none--datasets-none--model-framework-none--model-framework-version-none--child-paths-none-)

```py
Model.register(workspace_B, model_path, model_from_workspace_A.name)
```

I am not able to choose the version for this model. By default it sets the version of the registered model as 1 (if it does not exist) or **M_2 + 1**
if it already exists in workspace B.

Is there a workaround for this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Currently you cannot choose a custom version when registering a model, it is controlled by AzureML. A possible workaround would be to use tags when registering the models. You can use same tag when registering the models in different workspaces.

Comment: I understand. There is the option of using properties as well, right? What are the differences between properties and tags? Is it simply that tags can be updated? Thanks!